# Reliable text encoding function for Highcharts

Tags: encoding, highcharts

I want a reliable function for encoding chart titles, subtitles, series names etc in Highcharts. Normal HTML encoding functions don't work.

If I have a string client-side, I've settled on simply replacing `<` with `&lt;` for now:

```
function highchartsEncode(s) {
    return s.replace(/</g, "&lt;");
}
```

When building up a chart in an ASP.Net MVC view I use:

```
string HighchartsEncode(string s) 
{
    return HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(s).Replace(@"\u003c", "&lt;");
}
```

However, I can't figure out how I can encode a string for Highcharts so that it will show `&lt;` and this bothers me (imagine you're wanting to chart the frequency of the use of html entities).

#### Background

The [Highcharts Labels and String Formatting](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/label-and-string-formatting) help tells us:

> Texts and labels in Highcharts are given in HTML, but as the HTML is
>   parsed and rendered in SVG, only a subset is supported. The following
>   tabs are supported: `<b>, <strong>, <i>, <em>, <br/>, <span>`. Spans can
>   be styled with a style attribute, but only text-related CSS that is
>   shared with SVG is handled.
>
> Most places where text is handled in Highcharts, it is also followed
>   by an option called useHTML. When this is true, the text is laid out
>   as HTML on top of the chart. This allows for full HTML support and can
>   be a good idea if you want to add images in your labels, tables in
>   your tooltip etc. The downsides are that it will always be laid out on
>   top of all other SVG content, and that it is not rendered the same way
>   in exported charts. Using HTML also works around some older browser
>   bugs with bi-directional text. Read more under Internationalization.

So if I don't use useHTML, how should I encode arbitrary strings so that they are displayed verbatim in Highcharts? Highcharts seems to handle some entities, e.g., `&lt;`, but not others, e.g., `&amp;`, so I can't simply encode text using standing HTML encoding functions.

Here are some tests to see what will happen with a few different cases:
http://jsfiddle.net/franzo/2nRPS/

Any suggested improvements to the above?

Comment: A nice related improvement to Highcharts would be a setting to treat text properties like this literally, so that we didn't have to do special encoding.